# Simplest way to get the lesser of two BigDecimal values in Java

Tags: java, bigdecimal, compareto

Is there some way to determine which of two [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) objects is the lower (smaller) number that is simpler than an `if` or a [ternary operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) calling [`BigDecimal::compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#compareTo(java.math.BigDecimal))?

Given:

```
BigDecimal x = … ;
BigDecimal y = … ;
```

Either:

```
if( x.compareTo( y ) < 0 ) {
    return x ;
} else {
    return y ;
}
```

Or:

```
BigDecimal lower = ( x.compareTo( y ) < 0 ) ? x : y ;  // If x is smaller than y, use x. If x is greater than or equal to y, use y.
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Actually, there's a `min` method in the `BigDecimal` class.

```
BigDecimal min = x.min(y);
```

Answer (score 8):

The API supports it. See [`BigDecimal.min()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#min-java.math.BigDecimal-).